# What will happen to SQL Service Account when SQL Server is uninstalled?

Tags: sql-server

We are planning to downgrade from enterprise/standard version of SQL server to Developer Edition. We will move the existing system and user database to the Dev Edition. Are we gonna need to request for a new Service Account to be created for the SQL Services of the developer edition?

For this kind of activity what can you suggest? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Voted to migrate this question to the [DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com) site of the network. You'll certainly get quality answers there.

Comment: I thought you could do an Edition "upgrade" between editions and so not have to un/re-install from scratch anyway.